# Raphael is not defined error while using Treant.js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make an organizational flow chart for which i'm trying to use the treant.js. Below is my code. I'm getting this Raphael is not defined error which i'm unable to resolve.Kindly help me out with this.What could be the reason pls?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/treant-js/1.0/Treant.css" integrity="sha256-oihWe0KdtBd8G96a/F7odmMuPQowZ9lsl1LZT7m51GM=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div onclick="spaLoad()">click</div>
        <div id="tree-simple"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function spaLoad(){

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET","https://api.myjson.com/bins/xf2rt",true);
                xhr.send();

                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function () {

                        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){

                            var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            var orgChart = new Treant(obj);

                            }

                        }
                    }   
        </script>
    <!--    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/treant-js/1.0/Treant.js" integrity="sha256-znpgHNqR9Hjjydllxj3UCvOia54DxgQcIoacHEXUSLo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Treant.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "chart": {
    "container": "#tree-simple"
  },
  "nodeStructure": {
    "text": {
      "name": "Parent node"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "text": {
          "name": "First child"
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "name": "Second child"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it now...got to know that raphael is another js library which is been referred by the treant.js

EDIT:

```
> <script
> src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.js"
> integrity="sha256-MPXjTSEImVJI1834JAHubdK7Lts1VTUPJmCQ9zKAjyA="
> crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

adding this made it wrk :  )